# Does the word ”attention” have a verb?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, nouns, british-english

I studied the nominalisation, but I'm so confused if the noun ”attention” regards as nominalisation, and if say so, what its verb?

Comment: See here: [link](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=attention)

Answer (score 3):

If I pay *attention* to your question, I am *attending* to your question. The verb is attend.

> *Attend* = *to give attention to what someone is saying*
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/attend)